# Fit curve to two lines

Tags: calculus, curves, approximation-theory

I'm currently making a mobile game. Using two "connected" lines, I'd like to find the equation for the curve that fit these. The curve would model the trajectory of a projectile. How do i fit a cubic function to the two "connected" lines?
[image: example]

Comment: perhaps you can look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve

Comment: Where do you want the peak of the cubic equation relative to where the two lines meet? Also, can you find the slope of the two lines?

Comment: @AlgorithmsX The peak should be at around 10% less than the difference between p1.y and p2.y. The slopes are known yes.

Comment: @Hikaru Thanks, i tried the beizer curve approach and it worked wonderfully. Only three lines of code!

Answer (score 1):

Assume $p_1=(x_1,y_1)$ and is the left point,$p_2=(x_2,y_2)$ and is the right point, $m_1$ is the slope of the line through $p_1$, and $m_2$ is the slope of the line through $p_2$.

Solve the equations for $\{a_0,a_1,a_2,a_3\}$:
$$\begin{align}
a_0x_1^3+a_1x_1^2+a_2x_1+a_3&=y_1\\
a_0x_2^3+a_1x_2^2+a_2x_2+a_3&=y_2\\
3a_0x_1^2+2a_1x_1+a_2&=m_1\\
3a_0x_2^2+2a_1x_2+a_2&=m_2
\end{align}$$

The first two equations will give you a set of values of $\{a_0,a_1,a_2,a_3\}$ such that the cubic $a_0x_1^3+a_1x_1^2+a_2x_1+a_3$ goes through $p_1$ and $p_2$.

The last two equations take the slope of the two lines in consideration by finding the derivative of the cubic.

Also, as Hikaru said in the comments, check out [Bézier Curves](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve). They come up a lot in computer programming, animation, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i tried the beizer curve approach and it worked wonderfully.

Answer (score 0):

At time $t=0$ you are in point $P_0$ and have velocity $v_0$.

At time $t=1$ you are in point $P_1$ and have velocity $v_1$.

You can make a (quadratic) weight function to take care of the transition.

E.g. $x(t) = (P_0 + v_0*t)(1-t)^2 + (P_1 + v_1*(1-t))t^2$

Be careful of the sign of $v_1$ though.

For practical purposes, you could modify the velocity weight.

(If time $t$ is already in your calculations, use $\lambda$)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i tried the beizer curve approach and it worked wonderfully.

Answer (score 0):

- Given  slopes m1,m2
- First point is origin and for convenience of calculation *assume* second tangent drawn at point of inflection
- Coordinates of the second point not necessary under this assumption, it can be subsequently found

Let the equation of cubic be

$$ y = x^3 - 3 A x^2 + m1 \, *x \tag1 $$

$$ y'= 3 x^2-6 A \,x + m1 \tag2 $$

$$ y^{''} = 6\,x - 6 A =0, \,\rightarrow \, x= A \tag3$$

Let slope at PI $x=A$ be m2

$$ y^{'} =3 A^2 -6 A \cdot A + m1 = m2 \tag4$$

Simplify

$$ A =  \sqrt{(m1-m2)/3} \tag5 $$

Plug in into 1)

$$ y = x^3 - \sqrt{3 (m1-m2)} x^2 + m1 * x \tag6 $$

$$ y2 = A^3 - \sqrt{3 (m1-m2)} A^2 + m1 * A \tag7 $$

When value of $A$ is plugged in, you will find $y2$ involves *only the slopes*

For example take $ m1=0.5, m2= -1, \rightarrow A= 0.7071 \tag8 $[image]

$$ y = x^3- 1.5 *1.4142 x^2 -0.5 x \tag 9 $$

which *can be written as a formula* in terms of  given slopes. It is given here upto inflection point, the full cubic is not sketched.